# Cron Job every second week day

Tags: cron, cron-task

I need a cron job to run every second weekday for example.

If cron job last ran on a Thursday it should run on the next Monday.

The re-run on Wednesday and again on Friday again and on Tuesday and again on Thursday bring it back to the start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run it every weekday, and have the script set a flag in a file that says whether it did the work the on the previous run. If it did, it skips the work that time and inverts the flag.

Comment: The issue with this is it will run on saturday and sunday but I could always just make the cron job run monday to friday.

Comment: I said "run it every weekday", not "run it every day".